# The results are changed after appending to a list in recursive calls

Tags: python, list, recursion

Below is a python program to place eight queens on a 8*8 grid where no two queens are on the same rows, columns and diagonals.

The program looks correct but when I append the position list *columns*  to the list *results*, it changes the values of the early members in the list.

```
GRID_SIZE = 8
def placeQueen(row, columns):
  if(row == GRID_SIZE):
    print(columns) # it is where I print the positions
    return [columns] # it is where I append the positions 

  results = []
  for col in range(GRID_SIZE):
    if(checkVlaid(row, col, columns)):
      columns[row] = col
      results += placeQueen(row+1, columns)
  return results


def checkVlaid(row0, col0, columns):
  for row in range(row0):
    if(columns[row] == col0):
      return False
    if(abs(row - row0) == abs(columns[row] - col0)):
      return False
  return True  



def Test():
  columns = [-1]*GRID_SIZE
  print placeQueen(0, columns) #the results are different from what I originally appended


Test()
```

Comment: You are adding **the same** `columns` list multiple times into the `results`. You need to add new lists into `results` instead.

Comment: python uses `snake_case`, not `camelCase`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're repeatedly appending the same instance of `columns` to the results list. Here's a simplified example of what's happening

```
>>> results = []
>>> columns = ["original column value"]
>>> results.append(columns)
>>> results.append(columns)
>>> results
[['original column value'], ['original column value']]
>>> columns[0] = "A new value"
>>> results
[['A new value'], ['A new value']]
>>>
```

To get around this you need to make a copy of the columns list so that you don't modify the columns already appended to the results

A simple way to copy a list is to slice it via `columns = columns[:]`

Copying the `columns` list in the `placeQueen` function should fix the problem

```
def placeQueen(row, columns):
    # creates a copy of the columns list
    columns = columns[:]
    if (row == GRID_SIZE):
        print(columns)  # it is where I print the positions
        return [columns]  # it is where I append the positions


    results = []
    for col in range(GRID_SIZE):
        if (checkVlaid(row, col, columns)):
            columns[row] = col

            results += placeQueen(row + 1, columns)

    return results
```